# VBScript For Each problems

Tags: arrays, for-loop, vbscript

I'm confused as to how to do a for-each loop for an array of objects.  Currently, my methods are getting me errors in one of two ways.  Either the for loop executes, and runs into problems because it thinks the class variables are undefined, or it runs into the issue that the object type is an illegal assignment.

Here's the class I defined:

```vb
Class url_Link
     Public title, link
     Public Default Function Init(newTitle, newLink)
         title = newTitle
         link = newLink
         Set Init = Me
     End Function
End Class
```

For reference, the errors I get are:

> Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a01f5'
>   Illegal assignment: 'url_Link'
>   line 674

using this code snippet:

```html
<% for each x in systemSettingsArray%> 
<tr>
<td class='nograph'><A href='<%x.link%>'><%x.title%></a></td>
</tr>
<%next%>
```

and when I change `url_Link` to `x`, I get this error:

> Invalid procedure call or argument "link"

Code that creates objects and populates the array:

```vb
Dim systemSettingsArray(1)
Dim link
Dim arrayCounter
arrayCounter = 0

Set systemSettingsArray(arrayCounter) = (New url_Link)("Account Administration", "Maintenance/Account_Admin.asp")
arrayCounter = arrayCounter + 1
Set systemSettingsArray(arrayCounter) = (New url_Link)("Time Approval", "Maintenance/system_Time_Approval.asp")
```

Comment: I also get the invalid procedure call or argument error if I change this to a for i=0 to UBound(systemSettingsArray) and change the calls to systemSettingsArray(i).link

Comment: how do you populate systemSettingsArray?

Comment: code to build objects and populate the array has been added.

Comment: thanks for the code; according to my tests, it 'works' as long as you avoid the error pointed out by Ansgar - using the class name as variable name.

Comment: I have gotten it to work, except now it displays nothing instead of the error code.  Any thoughts why it would be doing that

Comment: Some testing notes for clarity.  Inside the for loop I get an invalid procedure call error, but using practically the same code outside the for loop it will display properly.    This is very confusing

Comment: Let me phrase what I just said a little better.  Putting the variable call outside the html tags makes it work fine (I did a response.write(systemSettingsArray(i).title)   and a response.write(systemSettingsArray(i).link) and both work fine, its when it is in the html that is gets screwy)

Comment: It turns out that the issue is that I am missing an equals sign.  The asp tags should be <%= %> not <% %>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't make `url_link` a class name *and* a variable name at the same time. Also, I don't see you initializing `url_link` objects anywhere. An instance of a custom class must be created like this:

```
Set linkobj = New url_link
```

or like this, when you have a method that returns a refernce to the object itself (in your case `Init`):

```
Set linkobj = (New url_link).Init("foo", "bar")
```

Marking the method as `Default` allows you to omit the explicit method call, so you can write the above as

```
Set linkobj = (New url_link)("foo", "bar")
```

Comment: I just didn't include it in the code listed.  I will add it to the code.

Comment: You still can't use the same name for class and loop variable even after you initialized `systemSetingsArray`. Please update your question with the code where you replaced `url_link` with `x`.